# Angular peerDependencies for libraries using Angular 12+

Tags: angular, npm, package.json

Since Angular v12, a library is able to be on a lower version of Angular than the application that uses the library, but the application must be on a version the same version or higher than the library. Which means having a `peerDependency` of `"@angular/core": "^12.0.0"` does not allow for a user of the library to go above 12 as they will get errors during the install process if they were to use a higher version:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree  
...  
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry  
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps  
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Is there a correct way to support this for an angular library?